# Is there a limit to the number of coordinates used to create a heatmap layer with Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there a limit to the number of coordinates that can be used when creating a single heatmap layer using the Google Maps API v3?

I have around 5000 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no limit of the number of points for google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer.

But if you want to put bunch of points to HeatmapLayer, FusionTables would be better performance.

Comment: Fusion Tables have a 1000 point limit.  I am looking at mapping over 5000 points.

Comment: Most probably you will hit performance limit: [this link](http://osdir.com/ml/google-maps-js-api-v3/2012-08/msg00078.html) mentioned 15,000 points with IE8.